# Transforming random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Lets say we have 2 random variables with Exponential distribution

$$X\sim\text{Exp}(2),\ Y\sim\text{Exp}(1/3)$$

And we want to calculate expected value of its transformation: e.g $\text{E}(2X-3Y+1)$

We do know what $\text{E}(A+B) = \text{E}(A) + \text{E}(B)$

However how can we treat this problem? Should we treat it such as

$\text{E}(2X-3Y+1) = \text{E}(2X + 0) + \text{E}(-3Y+1)$

or

$\text{E}(2X-3Y+1) = \text{E}( 2X  + Z )$   where $Z = (-3Y + 1)$

What is the right way to approach this problem? Thanks for help

Comment: The right thing to do is realize instantly that $E(2X-3Y+1)=2EX - 3EY +1$ and then worry about what $EX$ and $EY$ are.  The hard part of the problem is knowing whether $EX=2 $ or $EX=1/2$.

Comment: Either way works

Answer (score 1):

What you've written is identical (but the introduction of $Z$ introduces an extra unneccessary step). The rule you've written is correct and from it follows:

$$E(2X - 3Y + 1) = E(2X) - E(3Y) + 1 = 2E(X) - 3E(Y) + 1$$

Comment: Thanks for asnwer, however why do we introduce formula such as E(aX+B)= aEX + b? I mean eventually for E(2X) we would have to do E(2x + 0 ) or just literally multiply E(X) by 2?

Comment: @Johnyb Correct, I've added an extra step.